# Codeigniter all urls are being routed to default controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, .htaccess, url

I'm hoping someone can give me a suggestion on how to fix this.  I've developed a codeigniter app and just uploaded it to a godaddy subdomain.  It was working perfectly locally, however when running it at `ci.site.com`, all urls are being routed to the default controller. For instance, say my default controller is set to `$route['default_controller'] = 'home/index';`.  If I go to `ci.site.com`,  the home controller loads the index method just fine, however when going to `ci.site.com/users/index`, I'm routed back to `home/index` even though the url reads `ci.site.com/users/index`.

This is what my `/.htaccess` looks like, the CI app and `.htaccess` are in document root :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

I've deployed several CI apps and have never run into this problem.  Both my `base_url` and `index_page` config parameters are correct, I just can't seem to figure it out.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: what about `route.php`

Comment: Do you mean `routes.php`?  I'm defining `users/index` as `$route['users/index'] = 'users/index';` `$route['users'] = 'users/index';`

Comment: I've also tried every `uri_protocol` option with same results.

Comment: Your default controller should look like this `$route['default_controller'] = 'home'`

Comment: please edit your post and show us `routes.php`, thanks

Comment: Finally found the problem, apparently with GoDaddy, sometimes adding `Options +FollowSymLinks` to the top of .htaccess is needed.  Thanks for all of the suggestions!

Comment: Maybe you could write that as an answer and accept it in order to help other people having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this. The server you are now on likely does not have the module mod_rewrite enabled. Thus, the IfModule !mod_rewrite.c is TRUE.